Assign a specific value for the most recent date in another cell in Excel
I'm looking for a formula that assignes value based on the most recent date. So for the same name in one column I need to assign "new" for the most recent date and "old" for all older dates.
In the expected result I would need to put a function that I can apply for thousands of records.


Maybe =IF(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$A2)=$B2,"New","Old") or if you use a structured Excel table:  =IF(MAXIFS([Date],[Name],[@Name])=[@Date],"New","Old")


Formula in C2:
=IF(MAP(A2:A8,B2:B8,LAMBDA(x,y,MAXIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,x)=y)),"New","Old")

